# Wireless Ralink USB Adapter doesn't work properly in Kali Linux 2021

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux, virtualbox

I want to make it as simple as possible.
So I have downloaded Kali Linux 2021 latest version on my VirtualBox and my host machine runs Windows 10.

I bought a USB wireless adapter which has a Ralink RT5370 chipset (supports monitor mode). I just completed my Kali virtual setup and it is completely fresh.

Yet, my USB wireless adapter doesn't work in VirtualBox Kali but works in my host machine (Windows 10).

In Kali, I can see wlan0 in `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` (which means Kali can see the adapter). I can execute `ifconfig wlan0 down/up` but it doesn't scan any networks. It doesn't show any network in wireless settings and `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` returns `no results`.

And there are 5-6 networks around me (I can see them in host machine). So what should I do to make my adapter work in fresh Kali Linux setup? I can provide any command output information (like `lsusb`) you can just ask for them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to enable USB passthrough for that device, then you may need to install a 3rd party driver

Comment: @johndoe Thanks for the answer.There is a driver here : https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandwifi/rt5370
Can you help me downloading it?

Comment: Try to find one in your kali repo first if at all possible so theres gpg verification built into the install process

Comment: @johndoe Well I tried "apt-get install firmware-ralink" and some firmwares with that but they all were already downloaded. Is that what you mean? If not I would really appreciate if you can help me what to execute in the terminal to achieve what you mean. Thaks.

Comment: Thats what I was referring to, so if you already tried that then it must be another issue. Did you enable USB passthrough (When in the VM, go to "Devices"->"USB" and select the device you want to be used) . If Windows can use the adapter, then it won't work in the virtual machine

Comment: @johndoe Yeah I also added the USB adapter to that list. Since it shows the wlan0 in ifconfig doesn't it mean that it is connected to Kali? Also I am working on this a couple of days and I made it work 4-5 times. It just worked perfectly with "iwlist scan" and "airodump" but I dont know why. It just works and doesn't work after that.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb) you need to install `firmware-misc-nonfree` providing the `rt2800usb` module driver to make the `RT5370` chipset working.

To install the  `firmware-misc-nonfree` package after adding `non-free` to your sources.list:

```
echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. Yet, I did exactly what you said but it doesn't seem to work unfortunately... Btw the last command "sudo apt install firmware-nonfree" won't get executed it sais no package or smth like that basically nothing to install with that name.

Comment: @Cemeb I have update my answer.